# laravel - database not updating

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Welcome ! I made an simple app where user has it's own notes. I'm using foreign key and relationships ( belongsTo, hasMany). When i add new note and choose to which user it belongs it's ok, but when i try to update it change all besides user.

Pilot model:

```
 class Pilot extends Model
    {
      protected $table = 'pilots';
        /**
         * The attributes that are mass assignable.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $fillable = [
            'name', 'phone', 'email',
        ];

        public function note() {
          return $this->hasMany(Note::class);
        }
    }
```

Note model:

```
class Note extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'notes';
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'data', 'zadanie', 'uwagi', 'pilot_id',
    ];

    public function pilot() {
      return $this->belongsTo(Pilot::class);
    }
}
```

Notes Controller ( store  edit and update function)

```
public function store(Request $request)

{

    $this->validate($request, [

        'data' => 'required',

        'zadanie' => 'required',

        'uwagi' => 'required',





    ]);


    $note = new Note ();

    $note->data = $request->data;
    $note->zadanie = $request->zadanie;
    $note->uwagi = $request->uwagi;
    $note->pilot_id = $request->pilots;


    // Commit to the database

    $note->save();


    return redirect()->route('uwagi.index')

                    ->with('success','Uwagi dodane poprawnie');

}
public function edit($id)

{

    $note = Note::find($id);
    $pilots = Pilot::all();

    return view('uwagi.edit',['note'=>$note, 'pilots'=>$pilots]);

}
public function update(Request $request, $id)

{

    $this->validate($request, [

        'data' => 'required',

        'zadanie' => 'required',

        'uwagi' => 'required',

        'pilot_id' =>'required',

    ]);


    Note::find($id);
    $note->data = $request->data;
    $note->zadanie = $request->zadanie;
    $note->uwagi = $request->uwagi;
    $note->pilot_id = $request->pilots;


    // Commit to the database

    $note->save();

    return redirect()->route('uwagi.index')

                    ->with('success','Zaktualizowano poprawnie');

}
```

Edit blade:

```
<div class="panel panel-transparent">
  {!! Form::model($note, ['method' => 'PATCH','route' => ['uwagi.update', $note->id]]) !!}
<div class="panel-heading">
<div class="panel-title">Dodaj Uwagę
</div>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
<h3>Wybierz ucznia oraz dodaj do niego uwagę</h3>
<p>Wszystkie pola są wymagane</p>
<br>
<div>


</div>
</div>
</div>

</div>
<div class="col-sm-7">

<div class="panel panel-transparent">
<div class="panel-body">
{!! Form::open(array('route' => 'uwagi.store','method'=>'POST')) !!}
<p>Dane</p>

  <label>Pilot</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="pilot" name="pilots">
    @foreach($pilots as $pilot)
      <option value="{!! $pilot->id !!}">
        {!! $pilot->name !!}
      </option>


    @endforeach
  </select>
  </div>

<div class="row clearfix">
<div class="col-sm-6">
<div class="form-group form-group-default required">
<label>Data</label>
  {!! Form::date('data', null, array('placeholder' => 'Data','class' => 'form-control ')) !!}

</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
<div class="form-group form-group-default required">
<label>Zadanie</label>
{!! Form::text('zadanie', null, array('placeholder' => 'Zadanie','class' => 'form-control ')) !!}
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6">
<div class="form-group form-group-default required">
<label>Uwagi</label>
{!! Form::textarea('uwagi', null, array('placeholder' => 'Uwagi','class' => 'form-control ')) !!}
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>



<br>


<button class="btn btn-success btn-cons m-b-10" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span class="bold">Dodaj</span></button>
<a href="{{ route('pilot') }}"><button class="btn btn-info btn-cons m-b-10" type="button"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i> <span class="bold">Powrót</span>
</button></a>
      {!! Form::close() !!}
</div>
```

It changes everything besides pilot to whom belongs note.

Regards and thank you for help

Comment: Have you closed your second Form? and i don't think you need to specify the method since it's `model-binding`.

Comment: Where is your update function?

Comment: @eddythedove check update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your update function you are not getting the note object. You do

```
Note::find($id);
```

Do this instead

```
$note = Note::find($id);
$note->pilot_id = $request->pilots;
$note->save(); // $note->update();
```

Also, your view, you open the Form twice, once with `Form::model()` (you don't close) and later on with `Form::open()`.

You need to close each form separately with

```
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Moreover, you defined the `select` only once, inside of form::open. You need to add it also inside Form::model().

```
<select class="form-control" id="pilot" name="pilots">
```